# Who has been killed by a Terminator, a Predator, and a Xenomorph?

Tags: the-terminator-series, alien-franchise, actor-identification, predator-series

The [in memoriam](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10650/19561) for Bill Paxton, over on meta, reads

> (...) Bill Paxton, one of only two actors to have the distinction of being killed by a Xenomorph, a Predator *and* a Terminator (...)

**Who's the other one?**

Comment: The answer is in a deleted comment on that same meta post :-)

Comment: all three franchises have been killed ;)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### [Lance Henriksen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000448/)

Henriksen is typically considered the correct answer, though whether or not he qualifies is more ambiguous than Paxton<sup>1</sup>:

- In the original *Terminator* film, Henriksen plays one of the detectives working the "Phone Book Killer" case. He's shot repeatedly during the T-800's attack on the police station, and we're presumably meant to understand that he was killed.

  That being said, he's never actually shown dead (he just kind of falls out of frame and we never see him again, or in later films), so it's not impossible that he survived
- In *Aliens*, he plays the robot Bishop, who gets ripped in half by the Xenomorph Queen shortly before the iconic power loader fight. However, being a robot and everything, this doesn't kill him; his top half is seen wriggling on the floor, and saves Newt from being sucked into space when Ripley opens the airlock. His head turns up in the third film, and Ripley has a short conversation with it before permanently switching it off (at Bishop's request).

  This is the most debatable "death" of the three, and I've seen two main arguments against counting it, neither of which are entirely meritless:

  1. Bishop is a robot and isn't capable of dying, in the strictest sense. That's a far more philosophical question than I'm comfortable answering, but it's worth keeping in mind
  2. Bishop doesn't "die" from these wounds, and in fact is "killed" by Ripley. He clearly survives his bifurcation (his top half saves Newt from being sucked into space when Ripley opens the airlock), and he's finally deactivated for good by Ripley in the third film
- In *Alien vs. Predator* he plays Charles Weyland. He tries to distract one of the Predators with an improvised flamethrower, and gets stabbed for his troubles. Of the three claims, this is the only unambiguous one.

That being said, Henriksen and Paxton also share the honour of being the only actors (or actresses) common to all three franchises, so they're the only ones even in the running.

---

<sup>1</sup> Though it should be noted that Paxton's claim isn't unambiguous either; his character in *The Terminator* is only thrown into a metal fence and it's possible, though admittedly unlikely, that he survived

Comment: It's interesting that [all of BIll Paxton's deaths are off screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHg6S4AYlb4), while all of Lance's are on.

Comment: Lance was also slated to *be* the Terminator at one point, before Arnold's agent got involved.

Comment: Slightly arguable, given that Bishop chooses to die in Alien 3.  Also from memory, Hendikson's detective was shot but we don't see whether he's actually killed or badly wounded. (Nit-picking, I know! :)

Comment: @Graham True, then again one of Paxton's "deaths" is just him being thrown into a fence by Arnie - it's definitely not clear (and possibly not even likely) that he died from that. Maybe better to say they're the only two to be attacked by all three.

Comment: "he doesn't actually 'die' until ... his mostly-functional head is discovered by Ripley in the trash" Wait, what?

Comment: Michael, in the Alien series he plays a robot, so not having a body isn't as big a problem for him as it would be for a human.

Comment: @alexgbelov I prefer the term "artificial human", myself.